# .NET Core Console App: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, httprequest

I have a .NET Core Console app, and I'm trying to send an HttpRequest to a locally running version of my application. I'm sending a POST request with an auth token from Microsoft to our authentication endpoint, and essentially just trying to validate it.

With each request, I run into the following exception:
`The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot`

I don't know much about certificates, so any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to the [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#os-x---certificate-not-trusted),and try the commands in it.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```